# Reactivate Gmail account without access to dashboard

Tags: gmail, account-management

I recently started a company with a colleague. We created a domain name and registered a Gmail account for our company. For various reasons, my colleague has left the company, and deactivated the company email account. He/she was in control of the dashboard. It was just deactivated two hours ago. We have a variety of mail being sent to this account and have no way to access it.

Is there a way to re activate the account, with me paying for it?

Answer (score -1):

Start by trying to create the account again as if it never existed in the first place.  By deactivating the account, you may have actually deleted it, in which case mail that is being sent to the account currently just bounces and is not being collected anywhere.